# How to pass null values in Stored procedure jpa 2.1

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm using JPA 2.1 to call stored procedure. I have 8 IN parameters in my stored procedure. One of the parameter(inRegionId) might be null.

When region id goes null in the stored procedure i got following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 8
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2176)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2100)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:931)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.execute(CallableStatement.java:859)
        at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:69)
        ... 98 more
```

Below is the named Query parameter:

```
 @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "AddUpdateCurrentLocation", procedureName =
 "AddUpdateCurrentLocation", parameters = {

 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class, name
 = "inSubscribedUserId"),
 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Double.class, name
 = "inLatitude"),
 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Double.class, name
 = "inLongitude"),
 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name
 = "inLocationAccuracy"),
 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name
 = "inLocationName"),
 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Boolean.class, name
 = "inISExactLocation"),
 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class, name
 = "inCountryId"),
 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class, name
 = "inRegionId")
 }
 )
```

Below is the code to call stored procedure:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("AddUpdateCurrentLocation");
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inSubscribedUserId", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inLatitude", Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inLongitude", Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inLocationAccuracy", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inLocationName", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inISExactLocation", Boolean.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inCountryId", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inRegionId", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

            query.setParameter("inSubscribedUserId", userCurrentLocation.getSubscribedUser().getId());
            query.setParameter("inLatitude", userCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            query.setParameter("inLongitude", userCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
            query.setParameter("inLocationAccuracy", userCurrentLocation.getLocationAccuracy());
            query.setParameter("inLocationName", userCurrentLocation.getLocationName());
            query.setParameter("inISExactLocation", userCurrentLocation.getIsExactLocation());
            query.setParameter("inCountryId", userCurrentLocation.getCountry().getId());

            if(userCurrentLocation.getRegion()!=null){
                query.setParameter("inRegionId", userCurrentLocation.getRegion().getId());  
            }else{

                query.setParameter("inRegionId", null); 
            }
```

I tried to set below hint properties one by one but got an error:

```
query.setHint("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.proc.param_null_passing", true);
query.setHint("hibernate.proc.param_null_passing", true);

 HHH000121: Ignoring unrecognized query hint [spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.proc.param_null_passing]
```

Can somebody help me out towards solving the issue.

Comment: if you are calling `setParameter` passing in null then your JPA provider is seemingly not passing that in to the `CallableStatement` correctly. Raise a bug on them if so

Comment: Can Somebody help me out the alternate approach to pass null values in stored procedure.

Comment: actually I came to think that setHint(...) SHOULD have worked, but it didn't. Moreover, Hibernate documentation of QueryHints class, that I have seen to be used with setHint function, does not list anything that looks like this parameter - which makes me think that setHint was not designed to pass this particular parameter. The only way I made this work in my case was by setting the global property

Answer (score 1):

You have to add "hints" in your Procedure definition and to specify the parameter name :

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
name = "AddUpdateCurrentLocation", 
procedureName = "AddUpdateCurrentLocation", 
parameters = { 
   @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Integer.class, name = "inSubscribedUserId"), 
   ...
}
hints = @QueryHint( name = "hibernate.proc.param_null_passing.inSubscribedUserId", value = "true" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. I finally ended up just using a native query

```
@Query(value = "{call AddUpdateCurrentLocation (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6, ?7, ?8)}", nativeQuery = true)
void AddUpdateCurrentLocation(int inSubscribedUserId, double inLatitude, double inLongitude, String inLocationAccuracy, String inLocationName, boolean inISExactLocation, int inCountryId, Integer inRegionId);
```